# Brightness & Lock missing in System Settings - can't change screen locking time

Tags: system, settings, lock

I am running 14.04.2 LTS. I want to change the time it takes to automatically lock the screen when I step away, but there is no Brightness & Lock option listed under the System Settings. I have searched using the Unity search icon on the side ribbon, but no success. How do I add or restore that function? Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, brightness settings are *not* listed under settings, AFAIK. I just checked. Instead, they are either on your monitor, embedded in your laptop (if you use one) or are with your graphics drivers. Usually, with an AMD GPU, typing `gksudo amdcccle` will open the Catalyst Control Center--here, you can edit brightness. Example:
[image: Catalyst Control Center]

If you use NVIDIA, just a search for "NVIDIA" in the dash should bring up a config.

Comment: waterlubber: thanks for replying - I appreciate learning that. However, I want to adjust the screen lock time, and according to the Ubuntu Help menu under the upper-right hand gear icon on my screen, that feature should be under the "Brightness & Lock" feature. But I don't have that feature listed on my system.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted your question. What kind of computer do you have? Drivers? You may be missing part of your gnome config...here's what mine looks like. http://i.snag.gy/ytK97.jpg

Comment: No worries, waterlubber. I am using a desktop HP Compaq 6000 Pro. Not sure about the drivers as I thought ubuntu automatically loaded whatever it needs. Certainly possible that I'm missing part of Gnome as Unity appears to be in control here. Here's my System Settings menu: http://postimg.org/image/wgdjzpz01/

Comment: Wow! That's totally different from what I expected! You are certainly missing a few components. Did you install kubuntu, or another variant, by mistake? Try looking up the unity control/gnome center in dash. For comparison, this is what mine looks like (with a theme): http://i.snag.gy/4abDC.jpg

Comment: As far as I know, I installed the full ubuntu 14.04 on my machine. I downloaded it from ubuntu.com last year when I bought my machine. When I searched for "gnome", here's what was returned: http://postimg.org/image/mighct17j/